# How to wrap text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can I allow the user to vertically paste three pictures into a `RichTextBox` and wrap the text as shown below?

[image]

How can I do it? I can't find any solutions.

Comment: @Vignesh Vino - I'm affraid Aleksey is asking about WinForms, not WPF solution

Comment: @Marek Apologies..Comment removed

Comment: This is even unable to do in `WordPad` so I don't think it's possible with a `RichTextBox`. That's some kind of limit of `Winforms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R

and the code I found

```
Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromFile("full_path_of_image_here");
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

Reference : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/3496/insert-image-in-richtextbox.aspx

Comment: This is just a guide to how to insert text and image. Don't you see that the image and text relation in the OP's picture? That's not easy with the features that a `RichTextBox` supports.